# Why does arguement dependent lookup not work for type aliasing in c++?

Tags: c++, typedef, using, argument-dependent-lookup

Considering the following minimal example, `function` is not found. Argument dependent lookup seems to fail. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array

namespace foo {
    using Values = std::array<int, 2>;
    void function(const Values& v) {std::cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << '\n';}
}

int main() {
    foo::Values v{1,2};
    function(v);
    return 0;
}
```

A possible solution is to import `function` by placing `using foo::function;` above main. Is there an alternative to avoid this using statement?

Comment: With option 1, `v` is of type `std::array<int, 2>`. The fact that it was given that type via a typedef is irrelevant.

Comment: Um, the question is about the code that's commented out, so it's not a minimal example. Show the code that doesn't work, not the code that does.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Why is it irrelevant? I would expect that the name `Values` (or `std::array<int,2>`) is added to the namespace `foo` by the `using` statement, similar to defining a struct in `foo`.

Comment: You would expect incorrectly. Associated namespaces for purposes of ADL are a property of the type of the argument, not the alias by which that type happened to be named in a declaration. The name `Values` is in the namespace `foo`; but the type of the argument is `std::array<int, 2>` which is in namespace `std` and doesn't mention `foo`. So ADL searches `std` and doesn't search `foo`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I would accept that as the answer to "why".

Answer (score 1):

A type alias is just that: an alias. It's not a separate type, and as such it can't really affect ADL rules.

You could in your example, change the declaration of `v` to `std::array<int, 2> v{1,1}` and it would have the same effect.

Comment: The point of aliasing is not to write `std::array<int,2>` in a more general context. Ok it is not a type, but can I get it to be treated as such in this context?

Comment: Yes, I'm not debating your usage of an alias at all - my point when mentioning this "replace" operation is to drive the nail that the two versions are 100% the same thing - even if considering ADL.

Comment: Ugly workaround would be to simply create a new class and publicly inherit from `std::array<int, 2>`. I don't like it though so I don't really want to add it to this answer.